# Updating UI in TableViewController: Who's responsible- The table or cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Let's say I'm retrieving a bunch of data from a service and parsing it in JSON.

When I set my cell's UI elements to the appropriate values based on the retrieved data, is it better to set it up in the table view cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod, or should I do it in the UITableViewCell in the didSet method for my JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your JSON parsed, you should call reloadData on you TableView.

Then the best approach I think would be to have a method in the cell allowing you to set it up like let's say

```
setup(withUser: User) {}
```

and call it from you cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there isn't a "right" way to do this.

Traditionally, TableViewCells were thought of as a View and so the controller of that view, the tableView, should be responsible for setting the information of that view. This would be why you see the attributes of cells being set in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

As time has passed, TableViews and their Cells have become more complex. The loading of cells has become less costly as device performance has improved, allowing them to do more without becoming a performance burden. This makes Cells more available to become more like a ViewController than a View, managing some of their own setup and data tracking.

At this point I think it depends on what you prefer or what design decisions your app adheres to as a whole.

Personally a prefer something like cell.update(with viewModel: viewModelType), but if you want to use apple's default cells or are using very simple cells, simply setting them up in cellForRow is the way to go.